# backgammon scenario

Tags: backgammon

When bearing off - there is one checker in the 6 spot, 0 in the five spot, several each in the 4, 3, 2 spots.  There are 2 opponent checkers in the one spot. The roll is double 5's.  I can't move the 6 down to the one spot as my opponent is blocking that spot.  Can I bear off checkers in the 4 spot? If so, three or four checkers?

Answer (score 2):

No, as per the [official backgammon rules](http://usbgf.org/learn-backgammon/rules-of-backgammon/) of the US Backgammon Federation you cannot move in this instance, and your turn is over.

> If there is no checker on the point indicated by the roll, the player must make a legal move using a checker on a higher-numbered point. If there are no checkers on higher-numbered points, the player is permitted (and required) to remove a checker from the highest point on which one of his checkers resides.

- Since you have no checker(s) on the five point you must make a legal move with those on the six point.
- As there are no such legal moves, your turn is over.
- You are explicitly required to use the rolls of five *only to move checkers on the six point, **while those exist***.